# John Locke on socks and identity : reference request

Tags: reference-request, identity, locke

I am aware that the question is somewhat vague, but I am trying to locate where in Locke's writings the argument about identity – exemplified with him repairing his socks again and again – is to be found. This example (i.e. that Locke darned his socks whenever they were torn, thus raising the question of the identity of the socks) appears sometimes in philosophy books / articles on identity, but I didn't manage to find to it any mention in Locke's writings themselves. Can someone help me with that? Also, if indeed Locke did not mention it, where does the "sock"-story appear for the first time with respect to Locke? Thanks!

Comment: That reminds me of Bertrand Russell's remark that you don't need the axiom of choice to pick out one shoe from each of infinitely many pairs of shoes; but you do need choice to pick out one sock. Are there many other philosophical sock stories?

Comment: Locke discusses identity in Book 2, Chapter 27 of An Essay Concerning Human Understanding, see [SEP, Locke on Personal Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/locke-personal-identity/). The sock example was recently [made up by Martin Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ship_of_Theseus_examples#Miscellaneous) in Philosophy for Dummies, the traditional example is the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).